# What is a verb for the action that an astronaut performs by moving in space?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is the verb form of "astronaut"?

I mean what is the action that an astronaut performs, by moving in space?

A dictionary gave me the word "astronavigation" which is absolutely wrong. This is a task done on Earth and not in space.

Comment: An astronaut gets flown into space. There are then many other tasks.

Comment: "Astronavigation" is in any case a noun. (And it refers to the science and practice of guiding aircraft through reference to celestial bodies.) There doesn't appear to be one. The OED defines "astronaut" as a "person who travels in space".

Comment: Might help to know the sentence for which you need the verb.

Comment: Uhm.. they [**moonwalk**](https://youtu.be/b6pomaq30Gg?t=47s)?

Comment: You are too dismissive of *astronavigate*.  A boat (or captain) *navigating*  a sea may be sailing across it rather than plotting a course; sense 2 in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/navigate). A spacecraft crossing the vast empyrean may well therefore be astronavigating it: not inspired but a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: What is the verb form of fireman?

Comment: @Mitch - Fight fires.

Comment: Stephen, here are some ideas: go into space, man a flight, carry out a space mission.

Comment: How about `Space exploration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for answering.

I finally found the term `Space exploration`.

Answer (score 1):

**spacewalk** 1. a task or mission performed by an astronaut outside a spacecraft in space. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spacewalk?s=t

Word Hippo gives these synonyms for **spacewalk**: *excursion, extravehicular activity, EVA, moonwalk* [this is specific to a spacewalk that occurs on the moon], *mission, task* http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/spacewalk.html

**space-flight** or **space flight**  1. the flying of manned or unmanned spacecraft into or in outer space. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spaceflight?s=t

Comment: Astronaut means "space-traveler" so perhaps "voyage dans l'espace".

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and verb it!  Everyone else is doing it. See this comic strip:  [Verbing weirds language.](https://bookishmonkey.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/verbing-weirds-language1.jpg) Why not the word astronaut, too?

> John Glenn really knew how to ***astronaut.***

OR

> I wish one day I could ***astronaut*** myself to the moon like Neil
>   Armstrong.

The following clip is from 1963 in an [Ebony magazine article.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_Gx3HzvAuMYC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=I%20love%20astronauting&source=bl&ots=ITt-KTkhpp&sig=eUF-En5FDVGPHDikfAy1WMi55yQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhzuSQ4rvUAhUK34MKHTL9DEoQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=I%20love%20astronauting&f=false)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Astronauts *fly* into space, *fly* to the moon, and *orbit* the earth. When the rocket engines are firing, they *rocket* into space.

An astronaut is a *space traveler*, so and astronaut **space travels** or **travels (through/in) space**.

It is derived from the Greek *astro* (space) and *nautēs* (sailor). (Various sources online.) However, while science fiction about space flight uses nautical terms in abundance (e.g., a *fleet* of star*ships* and the use of maritime ranks such as admiral), to sail through space is not so common (but not unheard of).